# Changing from PHP MYSQLI to PHP Data Objects (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hie there i need help changing this code to data objects (PHP PDO).I am having an issue with mysql statements. I got this somewhere online here is a working code

```
<?php

if($_GET['type']=="feesearch")
{
$aColumns = array( 's.id','s.sname','s.balance','s.fees','b.grade','s.contact','s.joindate');
    
    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "s.id";
    
    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = " student as s,grade as b ";
    
    
    
    /* 
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }
    
    
    /*
     * Ordering
     */
     $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }
        
        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }
    
    $cond = "";
    $condArr = array();
    if(isset($_GET['student']) && $_GET['student']!="")
    {
    $condArr[] = "s.sname like '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['student'])."%'";
    
    }
    
    if(isset($_GET['grade']) && $_GET['grade']!="")
    {
    $condArr[] = "b.id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['grade'])."'";
    
    }
    
    
    if(isset($_GET['doj']) && $_GET['doj']!="")
    {
    $Adate= explode(' ',$_GET['doj']);
    $month = $Adate[0];
    $year = $Adate[1];
    $months = array('January'=>'01','February'=>'02','March'=>'03','April'=>'04','May'=>'05','June'=>'06','July'=>'07','August'=>'08','September'=>'09','October'=>'10','November'=>'11','December'=>'12');
    
    $doj = $months[$month].'-'.$year;   
    $condArr[] = " DATE_FORMAT(s.joindate, '%m-%Y') = '".$doj."'";
    
    }
    if(count($condArr)>0)
    {
    $cond = " and ( ".implode(" and ",$condArr)." )";
    }
     
    $mycount = count($aColumns);
     
    $sWhere = " WHERE b.id=s.grade and s.delete_status='0' and s.balance>0 ";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch'])&& $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        
        $sWhere = $sWhere." and (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<$mycount ; $i++ )
        {
            
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
    

    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS   ".implode(", ", $aColumns)."
        FROM   ".$sTable."  ".$sWhere.$cond." ".$sOrder." ".$sLimit;
    
    $rResult = $conn->query($sQuery) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    
    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as rr
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = $conn->query( $sQuery) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch_assoc();
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal['rr'];
    
    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.") as cc
        FROM   ".$sTable." WHERE b.id=s.grade and s.delete_status='0' and s.balance>0  ";
    $rResultTotal = $conn->query( $sQuery ) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->fetch_assoc();
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal['cc'];
    
    
    /*
     * Output
     */
     
    if(isset($_GET['sEcho'])) 
    {
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );
    }else
    {
     $output = array(
        
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );
    
    }
    
     $row =array();
    while ( $aRow = $rResult->fetch_assoc()  )
    {
        
        
        $row = array(
                    html_entity_decode($aRow['sname'].'<br/>'.$aRow['contact']),
                    $aRow['fees'],
                    $aRow['balance'],
                    $aRow['grade'],
                    date("d M y", strtotime($aRow['joindate'])),
                    
                    html_entity_decode('<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="border-radius:0%" onclick="javascript:GetFeeForm('.$aRow['id'].')"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Collect Fee </button>')
                                        
                );
        
        $output['aaData'][] =$row;
        
    }
    
    echo json_encode( $output );

}



if($_GET['type']=="report")
{
$aColumns = array( 's.id','s.sname','s.balance','s.fees','b.grade','s.contact','s.joindate');
    
    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "s.id";
    
    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = " student as s,grade as b ";
    
    
    
    /* 
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }
    
    
    /*
     * Ordering
     */
     $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }
        
        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }
    
    $cond = "";
    $condArr = array();
    if(isset($_GET['student']) && $_GET['student']!="")
    {
    $condArr[] = "s.sname like '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['student'])."%'";
    
    }
    
    if(isset($_GET['grade']) && $_GET['grade']!="")
    {
    $condArr[] = "b.id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['grade'])."'";
    
    }
    
    
    if(isset($_GET['doj']) && $_GET['doj']!="")
    {
    $Adate= explode(' ',$_GET['doj']);
    $month = $Adate[0];
    $year = $Adate[1];
    $months = array('January'=>'01','February'=>'02','March'=>'03','April'=>'04','May'=>'05','June'=>'06','July'=>'07','August'=>'08','September'=>'09','October'=>'10','November'=>'11','December'=>'12');
    
    $doj = $months[$month].'-'.$year;   
    $condArr[] = " DATE_FORMAT(s.joindate, '%m-%Y') = '".$doj."'";
    
    }
    if(count($condArr)>0)
    {
    $cond = " and ( ".implode(" and ",$condArr)." )";
    }
     
    $mycount = count($aColumns);
     
    $sWhere = " WHERE b.id=s.grade and s.delete_status='0'  ";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch'])&& $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        
        $sWhere = $sWhere." and (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<$mycount ; $i++ )
        {
            
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
    

    
    
    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS   ".implode(", ", $aColumns)."
        FROM   ".$sTable."  ".$sWhere.$cond." ".$sOrder." ".$sLimit;
    
    $rResult = $conn->query($sQuery) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    
    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as rr
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = $conn->query( $sQuery) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch_assoc();
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal['rr'];
    
    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.") as cc
        FROM   ".$sTable." WHERE b.id=s.grade and s.delete_status='0'   ";
    $rResultTotal = $conn->query( $sQuery ) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->fetch_assoc();
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal['cc'];
    
    
    /*
     * Output
     */
     
    if(isset($_GET['sEcho'])) 
    {
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );
    }else
    {
     $output = array(
        
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );
    
    }
    
     $row =array();
    while ( $aRow = $rResult->fetch_assoc()  )
    {
        
        
        $row = array(
                    html_entity_decode($aRow['sname'].'<br/>'.$aRow['contact']),
                    $aRow['fees'],
                    $aRow['balance'],
                    $aRow['grade'],
                    date("d M y", strtotime($aRow['joindate'])),
                    
                    html_entity_decode('<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="border-radius:0%" onclick="javascript:GetFeeForm('.$aRow['id'].')"> Check Report </button>')
                                        
                );
        
        $output['aaData'][] =$row;
        
    }
    
    echo json_encode( $output );

}

?>
```

Very sorry that i have to post a very long code. After hours of trying, here is what i came up with.
I'm not sure where i am wrong or what i'm missing here. this one isn't working

```
<?php
// include("inc/session.php");
$conn = $pdo->open();

if($_GET['type']=="feesearch")
{
$aColumns = array( 's.id','s.sname','s.balance','s.fees','b.grade','s.contact','s.joindate');
    
    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "s.id";
    
    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = " student as s,grade as b ";
    
    
    
    /* 
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".stripslashes($_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            stripslashes($_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }
    
    
    /*
     * Ordering
     */
     $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".stripslashes( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }
        
        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }
    
    $cond = "";
    $condArr = array();
    if(isset($_GET['student']) && $_GET['student']!="")
    {
    $condArr[] = "s.sname like '%".stripslashes($_GET['student'])."%'";
    
    }
    
    if(isset($_GET['grade']) && $_GET['grade']!="")
    {
    $condArr[] = "b.id = '".stripslashes($_GET['grade'])."'";
    
    }
    
    
    if(isset($_GET['doj']) && $_GET['doj']!="")
    {
    $Adate= explode(' ',$_GET['doj']);
    $month = $Adate[0];
    $year = $Adate[1];
    $months = array('January'=>'01','February'=>'02','March'=>'03','April'=>'04','May'=>'05','June'=>'06','July'=>'07','August'=>'08','September'=>'09','October'=>'10','November'=>'11','December'=>'12');
    
    $doj = $months[$month].'-'.$year;   
    $condArr[] = " DATE_FORMAT(s.joindate, '%m-%Y') = '".$doj."'";
    
    }
    if(count($condArr)>0)
    {
    $cond = " and ( ".implode(" and ",$condArr)." )";
    }
     
    $mycount = count($aColumns);
     
    $sWhere = " WHERE b.id=s.grade and s.delete_status='0' and s.balance>0 ";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch'])&& $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        
        $sWhere = $sWhere." and (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<$mycount ; $i++ )
        {
            
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".stripslashes($_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
    
    
    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */

    $frams = $sTable."  ".$sWhere.$cond." ".$sOrder." ".$sLimit;
    $climpds = implode(", ", $aColumns);
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS   :climpds
        FROM  :frams";
    
    $rResult = $conn->prepare($sQuery);
    $rResult->execute(['climpds'=>$climpds, 'frams'=>$frams]);
    
    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as rr
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = $conn->query( $sQuery);
    $rResultFilterTotal->execute();
    $aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch();
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal['rr'];
    
    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(:sIndexColumn) as cc
        FROM   :sTable WHERE b.id=s.grade and s.delete_status='0' and s.balance>0  ";
    $srResultTotal = $conn->prepare( $sQuery );
    $rResultTotal->execute(['sIndexColumn'=>$sIndexColumn, 'sTable'=>$sTable]);
    $aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->fetch();
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal['cc'];
    
    
    /*
     * Output
     */
     
    if(isset($_GET['sEcho'])) 
    {
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );
    }else
    {
     $output = array(
        
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );
    
    }
    
     $row =array();
    while ( $aRow = $rResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
    {
        
        
        $row = array(
                    html_entity_decode($aRow['sname'].'<br/>'.$aRow['contact']),
                    $aRow['fees'],
                    $aRow['balance'],
                    $aRow['grade'],
                    date("d M y", strtotime($aRow['joindate'])),
                    
                    html_entity_decode('<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="border-radius:0%" onclick="javascript:GetFeeForm('.$aRow['id'].')"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Collect Fee </button>')
                                        
                );
        
        $output['aaData'][] =$row;
        
    }
    
    echo json_encode( $output );

}



if($_GET['type']=="report")
{
$aColumns = array( 's.id','s.sname','s.balance','s.fees','b.grade','s.contact','s.joindate');
    
    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "s.id";
    
    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = " student as s,grade as b ";
    
    
    
    /* 
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".stripslashes($_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            stripslashes($_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }
    
    
    /*
     * Ordering
     */
     $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".stripslashes( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }
        
        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }
    
    $cond = "";
    $condArr = array();
    if(isset($_GET['student']) && $_GET['student']!="")
    {
    $condArr[] = "s.sname like '%".stripslashes($_GET['student'])."%'";
    
    }
    
    if(isset($_GET['grade']) && $_GET['grade']!="")
    {
    $condArr[] = "b.id = '".stripslashes($_GET['grade'])."'";
    
    }
    
    
    if(isset($_GET['doj']) && $_GET['doj']!="")
    {
    $Adate= explode(' ',$_GET['doj']);
    $month = $Adate[0];
    $year = $Adate[1];
    $months = array('January'=>'01','February'=>'02','March'=>'03','April'=>'04','May'=>'05','June'=>'06','July'=>'07','August'=>'08','September'=>'09','October'=>'10','November'=>'11','December'=>'12');
    
    $doj = $months[$month].'-'.$year;   
    $condArr[] = " DATE_FORMAT(s.joindate, '%m-%Y') = '".$doj."'";
    
    }
    if(count($condArr)>0)
    {
    $cond = " and ( ".implode(" and ",$condArr)." )";
    }
     
    $mycount = count($aColumns);
     
    $sWhere = " WHERE b.id=s.grade and s.delete_status='0'  ";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch'])&& $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        
        $sWhere = $sWhere." and (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<$mycount ; $i++ )
        {
            
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".stripslashes($_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
    
    
    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $froms = $sTable."  ".$sWhere.$cond." ".$sOrder." ".$sLimit;
    $climpd = implode(", ", $aColumns);
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS   :climpd
        FROM  :froms";
    
    $rResult = $conn->prepare($sQuery);
    $rResult->execute(['climpd'=>$climpd, 'froms'=>$froms]);
    
    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as rr
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = $conn->prepare( $sQuery);
    $rResultFilterTotal->execute();
    $aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch();
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal['rr'];
    
    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(:sIndexColumn) as cc
        FROM   :sTable WHERE b.id=s.grade and s.delete_status='0'   ";
    $rResultTotal = $conn->query( $sQuery );
    $rResultTotal->execute(['sIndexColumn'=>$sIndexColumn, 'sTable'=>$sTable]);
    $aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->fetch();
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal['cc'];
    
    
    /*
     * Output
     */
     
    if(isset($_GET['sEcho'])) 
    {
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );
    }else
    {
     $output = array(
        
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );
    
    }
    
     $row =array();
    while ( $aRow = $rResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)  )
    {
        
        
        $row = array(
                    html_entity_decode($aRow['sname'].'<br/>'.$aRow['contact']),
                    $aRow['fees'],
                    $aRow['balance'],
                    $aRow['grade'],
                    date("d M y", strtotime($aRow['joindate'])),
                    
                    html_entity_decode('<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="border-radius:0%" onclick="javascript:GetFeeForm('.$aRow['id'].')"> Check Report </button>')
                                        
                );
        
        $output['aaData'][] =$row;
        
    }
    
    echo json_encode( $output );

}

?>
```

Comment: When you have an issue, it's a very good idea to narrow down **what** the issue is, **where** the issue happens, and any error messages that come up. A code dump with "it doesn't work" isn't very helpful.

Comment: That said, at a glance, [you cannot bind table and column names as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter). Parameterization is only for values.

Comment: @aynber i get this errror:-  DataTables warning (table id = 'tSortable22'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.

Comment: That would be a javascript error, and not very helpful. However, you can check the raw response in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to see what it's sending back. I'd also suggest checking your server's error logs.

Comment: Thanks @aynber let me try and see if i can win

Comment: You can't bind table and column names in mysqli, either. That's not an issue with changing from mysqli to PDO, the problem is with changing from substituting variable to using parameter bindings.